# Getting "Cannot resolve assembly 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'" in UWP project...?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, csproj, xamarin.uwp

I've created a working iOS app with Visual Studio 2017 using Xamarin.Forms and a PCL. Now I'm trying to create the UWP app. I've followed [the steps here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/), and when I build, I'm getting the error:

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Metadata file 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'

It says it's happening in the `MyProject.UWP` project, in the `MyProject.UWP.csproj` file. But there's no reference to that file in `MyProject.UWP.csproj` (no reference to anything iOS), and there's no reference to that file in the entire UWP project either. So where is it trying to be referenced?

I did notice there's a file in `MyProject.UWP\bin\` called project.assets.json. And while there are no references to 'Xamarin.iOS.dll', there are references to 'Xamarin.iOS10' - for example in the file list for the MR.Gestures package, I see listed a `"lib/Xamarin.iOS10/MR.Gestures.dll"` - not sure why there would be any iOS reference at all there, so that's a little suspicious...although it seems to reference all platforms, including windows phone and android, too, so maybe that's ok.

Comment: Any `lib/Xamarin.iOS10/****` references *could* cause that, `MR.Gestures.dll` is platform dependent and thus contains references to `Xararim.iOS` features.

Comment: Have you tried to clean IOS client project?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - sure have. I just discovered that I'm using a scanner dll reference in my UWP project - and that dll I believe is generated through another solution that has a single project (InfineaOmniLib) with 2 included references - `System` and `Xamarin.iOS`. I'm wondering if somehow the reference to Xamarin.iOS.dll is *within* the scanner .dll? (I may be displaying my ignorance here)

Comment: @jbyrd scanner dll ? Please show more deatil about the scanner .